How to use SASS partials in Tailwind @layer?
I was hoping I can segregate my tailwind component classes into multiple files and import them in the @layer components {}. And so I have created partial (underscored) .scss files .
My files are structured like so:
styles/
├─ components/
│  ├─ _my-button.scss
│  ├─ _my-spinner.scss
├─ index.scss

Where the partial files will contain my custom utility classes like:
/*_my-button.scss*/

.my-button {
  @apply ....
}

I tried importing them with @use (Note that @import is now marked as deprecated but I also tried it) like so:
/*index.scss*/

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer component {
  @use "./components/my-button";
}

But I cannot do it because the at-rules prohibits it.

⚠️ Heads up!
A stylesheet’s @use rules must come before any rules other than @forward, including style rules. However, you can declare variables before @use rules to use when configuring modules.

Error:
❌ [ERROR] This at-rule is not allowed here.
   ╷
08 │   @use "./components/my-button";

Update:
I currently am using @include and wrapped my individual component class files with @mixin. It works. However, I am not sure if this is a correct implementation.

You can have the @layers repeated, so in your partials, do:
@layer components {
  .my-button {
    @apply …
  }
}

And then in the main stylesheet:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@use "./components/my-button";


This was my first solution but I'm not sure why repeating @layer components doesn't work for me. no errors, just didn't see the style rules take effect

Consider checking that the my-button (or equivalent) exist as an unbroken string in a file covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration.
